# With function not working to load has many relation data laravel Model Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, eager-loading

I have these two model. 
This phone model is a common model which can be used to save and fetch the phone value for a user, customer, Employee and so on. So the meta_value is used to save the id of related model and meta_key is used to determine the model name relation.

```
/* Customer Model*/
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Customer extends Model {
    /**
     * Get the Phone List.
     */
    public function phones(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Phone','meta_value', 'id')
                    ->select('id as phone_id','contact_number as phone','contact_number','country_code','type','dial_code')
                    ->where('meta_key','customer');
    }
}
/* Phone Model*/
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Phone extends Model {
    /**
     * Get the customer that owns the phone.
     */
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'meta_value');
    }
}
```

I can't get the data of phones with customer data. It always returns

```
[relations:protected] => Array
    (
        [phones] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
            (
                [items:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

In My controller I do the following code.

```
/*This is the case when I want to get the data for a single customer.*/
        $customer = Customer::find('448')->with('phones')->get();
        print_r($customer); // It will return all customers with no phones value.

        $customer = Customer::find('448');
        print_r($customer);die; // It will return a single customer whose id is 448 with no phones value.

        print_r($customer->phones);die; // I can get the values of phones by this

        $customer = Customer::find('448')->with('phones');
        print_r($customer);die; // It will crash my postman when i hit this.

        /*This is the case when I want to get the data for multiple customers.*/
        $customers = Customer::where('id', '>', '447')->with('phones')->get();
        print_r($customers);die; // It will return multiple customer with empty phones value.

        // However when I iterate through the loop and get phones then I can get the phone value. 
        $customers = Customer::where('id', '>', '447')->get();
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $customer->phones = $customer->phones;
        }
        print_r($customers);die;
```

Only the iteration is working but I think that is not a good solution. Even I try load function but not working.

Comment: Not working @MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the required foreign key column `meta_value`:

```
->select('id as phone_id','contact_number as phone','contact_number','country_code',
    'type','dial_code','meta_value')
```

For a single customer you don't need eager loading:

```
$customer = Customer::find(448);
$phones = $customer->phones;
```

It also looks like you should use [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonas Staudenmeir You saved my day. I just only need to update my select array in the customer model and add 'meta_value' field. I will accept your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although I suspect that selecting the `phone_id` as `id` may have affected query from checking the relationship but a quick debug would be to remove this from the related function:

```
->select('id as phone_id','contact_number as phone','contact_number','country_code','type','dial_code')
                ->where('meta_key','customer');
```

And let the function `phones` be simply,

```
public function phones(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Phone','meta_value', 'id');
}
```

~**UPDATED**~

Then, you **need** to use `load` instead.

If you need to further do a check later on the relationship, then pass a callback to filter it:

```
$customer = Customer::find('448')->load(['phones' => function($query) {
    $query->where('meta_key','customer');
}]);
```

Or:

```
$customer = Customer::with(['phones' => function($query) {
    $query->where('meta_key','customer');
}])->find('448');
```

The initial problem is:

Using `with` and `get` on the result of the `find` creates another instance of the model for a fresh query hence you'll only get all the records of customer. You can use the `load` method, or if you'll use `with` then you'll have to set the filter at the end of the query functions.

For better understanding please check [Laravel documentation on Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: This solution is also return empty object,

Comment: do it without the closure.

Comment: Are you sure this relation is correct `$this->hasMany('App\Phone','meta_value', 'id');`?

Comment: Yes this relation $this->hasMany('App\Phone','meta_value', 'id') is right otherwise iteration never working

Comment: yes its correct. Did you check the corrections I made to the answer?

Comment: Yes I did, but I just need to add 'meta_value' field in select array of phone function under customer table. Thanx for your time. @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin