# Laravel Eloquent with() method works with 'where' but doesn't work with 'Model::find()'

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to have relationship between 3 tables, using Laravel Eloquent `with()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).
this is my code (*relationships are set in models*):

```
    $request_form = RequestForm::find(7)->with(['RequestFormsCheck' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->with('RequestFormsCheckOptions');
    }])->get();

    dd($request_form);
```

but this code returns all `request forms` except returning only `id = 7`
this is output:

```
Collection {#895 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => RequestForm {#796 ▶}
    1 => RequestForm {#797 ▶}
    2 => RequestForm {#798 ▶}
    3 => RequestForm {#799 ▶}
  ]
}
```

when I replace `->get()` with `->first()` it returns just `request form`, but its `id` is 1 :(

but this code works great:

```
        $request_form = RequestForm::where('id', 7)->with(['RequestFormsCheck' => function ($q) {
            $q->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->with('RequestFormsCheckOptions');
        }])->first();

        dd($request_form->toArray());
```

and this is its output (*this is what I expect to get*):

```
array:12 [▼
  "id" => 7
  "name" => "Jack"
  "email" => "jack@gmail.com"
  "telephone" => null
  "description" => "..."
  "site" => "http://branch.local/"
  "item_id" => 10
  "lang" => "en"
  "read" => 1
  "created_at" => "2018-05-15 11:09:47"
  "updated_at" => "2018-05-20 05:24:41"
  "request_forms_check" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:8 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "request_form_id" => 7
      "type" => 2
      "request_forms_check_options_id" => null
      "description" => "custom note"
      "created_at" => "2018-05-15 11:48:36"
      "updated_at" => "2018-05-15 11:48:36"
      "request_forms_check_options" => null
    ]
  ]
]
```

these are my migrations:

```
    Schema::create('request_forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('email', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('telephone', 20)->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('site', 100);
        $table->integer('item_id');
        $table->string('lang');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and

```
    Schema::create('request_forms_check_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 500);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this

```
    Schema::create('request_forms_checks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('request_form_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('request_form_id')->references('id')->on('request_forms')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('type')->comment("1: option, 2:description");
        $table->integer('request_forms_check_options_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('request_forms_check_options_id')->references('id')->on('request_forms_check_options')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50347680/5704410) but for record sake I'll explain again as I understand:

When you use `find()` method an instance of the Model is returned already (this is not query builder), this is why using `with()` on the result of find will do a fresh query on the database then calling `get()` on that returns the entire records whereas calling `first()` will return the first record (by id).

I suggested ways to go about this *in case* you still want to stick with `find()`

- Let the `find()` come after the query (eager loaded). Example:

  ```
  $request_form = RequestForm::with(['RequestFormsCheck' => function ($q) {
      $q->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->with('RequestFormsCheckOptions');
  }])->find(7);
  ```
- Use `load()` after find (Lazy loaded) - You have the result then load the related models. Example:

  ```
  $request_form = RequestForm::find(7)->load(['RequestFormsCheck' => function ($q) {
      $q->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->with('RequestFormsCheckOptions');
  }]);
  ```
- Stick with calling `with()` ( the one that worked) on the whole query before invoking the final result. I think this is the best way to do it, since you need only **one** RequestForm, then **many** relations to that

> My general understanding where `with()` works is on query builder, therefore you must still be getting together the query before `with()` will be relevant (this thought may need to be updated).

You may need to read more on [Eager Loading - in Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)